# Milliseconds separated by comma

Tags: r, date, time, milliseconds

I have the following data.frame called "data" (it is much larger but i just give the first lines as an example):

```
  Timestamp Weight Degrees
1 30-09-2016 11:45:00,000 38.19 40.00 
2 01-10-2016 06:19:57,860 39.12 40.00 
3 01-10-2016 06:20:46,393 42.11 41.00
```

I would like to convert the "Timestamp" to a date/time vector including milliseconds. This seems to be a problem because the milliseconds are separated by a comma.

Also, data.frame has mode "list" and Timestamp has mode "character" which clearly aren't right...

I have tried `data$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(data$Timestamp,format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS')` but I only get  `"2016-09-30 11:42:00 UTC"`, without the milliseconds. The mode however becomes "numeric", which should be a step in the right direction. I only have set `options(digits.secs=3)`.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = c("30-09-2016 11:45:00,000", "01-10-2016 06:19:57,860", "01-10-2016 06:20:46,393")
format(as.POSIXct(gsub(",", ".", x), format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS'), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS3')
#[1] "30-09-2016 11:45:00.000" "01-10-2016 06:19:57.859" "01-10-2016 06:20:46.392"
```

OR

```
x = c("30-09-2016 11:45:00,000", "01-10-2016 06:19:57,860", "01-10-2016 06:20:46,393")

#Converting to POSIXct
options(digits.secs=3)
y = as.POSIXct(gsub(",", ".", x), format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS', tz = "UTC")
y
#[1] "2016-09-30 11:45:00.000 UTC" "2016-10-01 06:19:57.859 UTC" "2016-10-01 06:20:46.392 UTC"

#Converting to numeric
as.numeric(y)
#[1] 1475253900 1475320798 1475320846

#Converting numeric back to POSIXct
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(y), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2016-09-30 11:45:00.000 UTC" "2016-10-01 06:19:57.859 UTC" "2016-10-01 06:20:46.392 UTC"
```

OR

```
x = c("30-09-2016 11:45:00,000", "01-10-2016 06:19:57,860", "01-10-2016 06:20:46,393")
library(lubridate)
options(digits.secs=3)
dmy_hms(gsub(",", ".", x))
#[1] "2016-09-30 11:45:00.000 UTC" "2016-10-01 06:19:57.860 UTC" "2016-10-01 06:20:46.393 UTC"
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work. However, "x" remains of mode "character". If I am to chart the data frame above, I need it to be of mode "numeric". Would you have a suggestion on how to convert "x" from "character" to "numeric"?

Comment: as.Date(x,format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS3') does not seem to do the trick

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect now